# Async request axios Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a few pictures in my react project which I get from my JSON file with axios,I need it to open in full screen when I click on the picture, so it works, but when I try to add some Redux to my code I get nothing on my page,  perhaps my choice of solution is not the right one.Im new at react so any help or suggestions would help me. have this code:

**Component**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Card from "@material-ui/core/Card";
import CardActionArea from "@material-ui/core/CardActionArea";
import CardContent from "@material-ui/core/CardContent";
import CardMedia from "@material-ui/core/CardMedia";
import Typography from "@material-ui/core/Typography";
import "../Pages/PortfolioStyle.scss";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";
import Image from "react-bootstrap/Image";
import { fetchArticleDetails } from "../Actions/action_1.js";
import { connect } from "react-redux";


 class Portfolio extends Component {
  state = {
    persons: [],
    show: false,
    close: false,
  };
  handleShowDialog = (id) => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, selected: id, show: true });
    console.log("cliked");
  };
  handleHideDialog = () => {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, show: false });
    console.log("closed");
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchArticleDetails();
    
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row justify-content-center">
          {this.state.persons.map((person) => (
            <Card key={person.id} className="col-3 axios-items">
              <CardActionArea>
                <CardMedia
                  component="img"
                  alt={person.alt}
                  height="140"
                  image={person.src}
                  title={person.title}
                  onClick={() => {
                    this.handleShowDialog(person.id);
                  }}
                />
                {this.state.show && this.state.selected === person.id && (
                  <Modal
                    show={this.state.show}
                    animation={true}
                    style={{ position: "absolute" }}
                    open
                    onClick={this.handleHideDialog}
                  >
                    <Modal.Body>
                      <Image
                        className="image"
                        src={person.src}
                        onClick={this.handleShowDialog}
                        alt="Img"
                        style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}
                      />
                    </Modal.Body>
                    <div>
                    <main>
          {this.props.isLoadingData ? (
            "Loading . . ."
          ) : (
            <div
              title={person.title}
          
            />
          )}
        </main>
                    </div>
                  </Modal>
                )}
                <CardContent>
                  <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                    {person.title}
                  </Typography>
                  <Typography
                    variant="body2"
                    color="textSecondary"
                    component="p"
                  >
                    {person.desc}
                  </Typography>
                </CardContent>
              </CardActionArea>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


const mapStateToProps = ({ data = {}, isLoadingData = false }) => ({
  data,
  isLoadingData
});
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  {
    fetchArticleDetails
  }
)(Portfolio);
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import rootReducer from "../Reducers/reducer.js";
import apiMiddleware from "../middleware/api.js";

const store = createStore(rootReducer, applyMiddleware(apiMiddleware));
window.store = store;
export default store;
```

**Reducer**

```
    SET_PORTFOLIO,
    API_START,
    API_END,
    FETCH_PORTFOLIO
  } from "../Actions/types.js";
  
  export default function(state = {}, action) {
    console.log("action type => ", action.type);
    switch (action.type) {
      case SET_PORTFOLIO:
        return { data: action.payload };
      case API_START:
        if (action.payload === FETCH_PORTFOLIO) {
          return {
            ...state,
            isLoadingData: true
          };
        }
        break;
      case API_END:
        if (action.payload === FETCH_PORTFOLIO) {
          return {
            ...state,
            isLoadingData: false
          };
        }
        break;
      default:
        return state;
    }
  }
```

**CreateAction**

```
import { SET_PORTFOLIO, API, FETCH_PORTFOLIO } from "./types";

export function fetchArticleDetails() {
  return apiAction({
    url: "http://localhost:3000/persons.json",
    onSuccess: setArticleDetails,
    onFailure: () => console.log("Error occured loading portfolio"),
    label: FETCH_PORTFOLIO
  });
}


function setArticleDetails(data) {
  return {
    type: SET_PORTFOLIO,
    payload: data
  };
}

function apiAction({
  url = "",
  method = "GET",
  data = null,
  accessToken = null,
  onSuccess = () => {},
  onFailure = () => {},
  label = "",
  headersOverride = null
}) {
  return {
    type: API,
    payload: {
      url,
      method,
      data,
      accessToken,
      onSuccess,
      onFailure,
      label,
      headersOverride
    }
  };
}
```

Thank u

Comment: Can you see in the redux devtools if your actions are dispatched, have the right data and cause the correct changes to the state? It would save us 98% of effort to see what's wrong with the code.

Comment: Actually, I don't know exactly how to do that, but when I run redux devtools all that I see is  @@INIT and GET_PICTURES. But in state/tree I see my array and loading: false

Comment: Not sure if you dispatched irrelevant action (GET_PICTURES) or posted irrelevant code (no code with that action at all). But if you were wondering why `API_START` didn't work then it's obvious from your devtools that it was never dispatched.